# Android Recyclerview with horizontal scrolling the rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

Not sure how to describe the issue, but here goes.

I'm trying to create a RecyclerView with a list of items and at the same time allow scrolling of most of the rows horizontally.

For instance, I have a list of players with the stats for each individual player on each row, however, there isn't enough room on the screen (especially phones) to display all the stats for each player.

So, I would like to list all the players in a RecyclerView, keeping their names visible while allowing to scroll the stats horizontally.

I hope the images show what I'm trying to do. The second image shows the horizontal scrolling of the stats.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: use nested reyclerview which scroll horizontally

Comment: OK, I'll that a try. I just didn't know what to call it.